# How to sum/divide array values in chart.js?

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

I have this variable to put in my chart:

```
var datiedu2 = {
            "labels": ['Lavori non terminati', 'Lavori in corso'],
            "datasets": 
                      [{
                           label: 'Numero',
                           data: [arrayItem['Value1'] + arrayItem['Value2']],
                           backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                           borderWidth: 1
                      }]
               };
```

I can't get to make sum or division with array items. These belong to a variable whose structure is like:

```
 var myJSON = [
  {
    "": 0,
    "Comune": "BONDENO",
    "PUNTEGGIOSCUOLA1516": 4.25,
    "Value 1": 63,
    "Value 2": 8,
    "Value 3": 17,
    "DANNO": 6,
    "Somma valori": 88,
  },
  {
    "": 1,
    "Comune": "CAVEZZO",
    "PUNTEGGIOSCUOLA1516": 3.75,
    "Value 1": 23,
    "Value 2": 2,
    "Value 3": 9,
    "DANNO": 8,
    "Somma valori": 34,

  }
```

What is the best option to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Just loop over the json array and then add the values to the sum and then add it to chart.

Answer (score 0):

Just loop over the json array and then add the values to the sum variable and then add it to chart.

This code will do:

```
var sum=0;
for(item of myJSON)
{
    let subsum=item["Value 1"]+item["Value 2"]+item["Value 3"];
    sum+=subsum;
}
```

Then update the code like this:

```
var datiedu2 = {
            "labels": ['Lavori non terminati', 'Lavori in corso'],
            "datasets": 
                      [{
                           label: 'Numero',
                           data: sum,
                           backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                           borderWidth: 1
                      }]
               };
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but how could I insert it in a function like `myJSON.forEach(function(arrayItem) {` etc. ?

Answer (score 0):

Sums the properties Value 1 and Value 2

```js
var myJSON = [{
    "": 0,
    "Comune": "BONDENO",
    "PUNTEGGIOSCUOLA1516": 4.25,
    "Value 1": 63,
    "Value 2": 8,
    "Value 3": 17,
    "DANNO": 6,
    "Somma valori": 88,
  },
  {
    "": 1,
    "Comune": "CAVEZZO",
    "PUNTEGGIOSCUOLA1516": 3.75,
    "Value 1": 23,
    "Value 2": 2,
    "Value 3": 9,
    "DANNO": 8,
    "Somma valori": 34,

  }
];



function getSum(arr) {
  const sum = arr.reduce((acc, x) => acc + x['Value 1'] + x['Value 2'], 0);
  return sum;

}
const result = getSum(myJSON);
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but how could I insert it in a function like `myJSON.forEach(function(arrayItem) {` etc. ?

Comment: hey, it's not what I was asking, sorry... I don't want the average. I am looking to sum corresponding values of Value 1 and Value 2...

Comment: how do I put it inside this code [codepen](https://codepen.io/dreamtheater96/pen/rNVpMzj) as the array item is already selected...

Comment: Don`t put the charts related things into the foreach loop, 1st prepare the data for the graph through foreach loop and then add that data to the graph. In current case you are binding graph element in each iteration.